# how to uncompress and view hadoop file

Tags: hadoop

In my project normal files are being moved to HDFS Location and file is stored as

B6p.3ED.UXHq_wLG_B06b.n.aw3AHOYL.eST.lzoe. This is something obfucated file and .lzoe means file is compressed. Can you please let me know if any way to uncompress this file in hadoop and view its content.

Comment: What is your system/distribution?

Comment: Sorry but Can you pls elaborate your question? usually its ecosytem testing, dev team are trying to ingest file into HDFS location, i need to test if files are getting dumped properly into HDFS location or not. So files are being dumped as the filename as mentioned above.so wanted to uncompress the file and view it contents

Comment: Can you pls elaborate yours :) ? I want to know what are you using / running, your hadoop distribution, OS, architecture, etc. So, it can make easier to give you steps/ instructions / command lines you can use to copy/uncompress/visualize the file.